# Check whether the list value is present in the dataframe column value. If so, replace the dataframe value with a list value; else leave it alone

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two tables in PySpark environment,

- `Table_A` contains 2 columns :- `id` and `X_code`
- `Table_B` contains 1 column :- `element_code`

Now I wanted to check,
If `element_code` in `Table_B` is contained in the `X_code` of `Table_A`,
and if so replace the `X_code` with the `element_code`, else keep the `X_code` as is.

Using Pyspark, how to build this
I'd be grateful for any assistance. Sincere gratitude

Comment: would be helpful if you added sample input and intended output data sets

Comment: And what type is `X_code`? what happens if an X_code "contains" several "element_code"?